# @Id is not set automatically on insert in entity bean

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss, ejb

I have a rather simple EJB application which consists of

**One Entity Bean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8450766960140252704L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="employee_number", nullable=false)
private int employeeNumber;
private String firstname;
private String inital;
private String lastname;
private int age;
private Date birthday;
private String street;
@Column(name="house_number")
private String houseNumber;
private String postalcode;
private String city;
private String department;
@Column(name="sallery_group")
private String salleryGroup;

public int getEmployeeNumber() {
    return employeeNumber;
}
public void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber) {
    this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getInital() {
    return inital;
}
public void setInital(String inital) {
    this.inital = inital;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}
public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getHouseNumber() {
    return houseNumber;
}
public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
}
public String getPostalcode() {
    return postalcode;
}
public void setPostalcode(String postalcode) {
    this.postalcode = postalcode;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public String getSalleryGroup() {
    return salleryGroup;
}
public void setSalleryGroup(String salleryGroup) {
    this.salleryGroup = salleryGroup;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("Employee Number: " + this.getEmployeeNumber() + "\n");
    sb.append("Firstname: " + this.getFirstname() + "\n");
    sb.append("Inital: " + this.getInital() + "\n");
    sb.append("Lastname: " + this.getLastname() + "\n");
    sb.append("Age: " + this.getAge() + "\n");
    sb.append("Birthday: " + this.getBirthday() + "\n");
    sb.append("Street: " + this.getStreet() + "\n");
    sb.append("House Number: " + this.getHouseNumber() + "\n");
    sb.append("Postalcode: " + this.getPostalcode() + "\n");
    sb.append("City: " + this.getCity() + "\n");
    sb.append("Department: " + this.getDepartment() + "\n");
    sb.append("Sallery Group: " + this.getSalleryGroup() + "\n");

    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if(obj == null || this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (obj == this)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Employee employee = (Employee)obj;
        return (
               ((this.getFirstname() == null && employee.getFirstname() == null) || (this.getFirstname().equals(employee.getFirstname()))) &&
               ((this.getInital() == null && employee.getInital() == null) || (this.getInital().equals(employee.getInital()))) &&
               ((this.getLastname() == null && employee.getLastname() == null) || (this.getLastname().equals(employee.getLastname()))) &&
               this.getAge() == employee.getAge() &&
               ((this.getBirthday() == null && employee.getBirthday() == null) || (this.getBirthday().equals(employee.getBirthday()))) &&
               ((this.getStreet() == null && employee.getStreet() == null) || (this.getStreet().equals(employee.getStreet()))) &&
               ((this.getHouseNumber() == null && employee.getHouseNumber() == null) || (this.getHouseNumber().equals(employee.getHouseNumber()))) &&
               ((this.getPostalcode() == null && employee.getPostalcode() == null) || (this.getPostalcode().equals(employee.getPostalcode()))) &&
               ((this.getCity() == null && employee.getCity() == null) || (this.getCity().equals(employee.getCity()))) &&
               ((this.getDepartment() == null && employee.getDepartment() == null) || (this.getDepartment().equals(employee.getDepartment()))) &&
               ((this.getSalleryGroup() == null && employee.getSalleryGroup() == null) || (this.getSalleryGroup().equals(employee.getSalleryGroup()))));

    }
}

}
```

**One Session Bean**

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class EmployeeManagementBean implements EmployeeManagement {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="EmployeePersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Employee create() {
    return new Employee();  
}

@Override
public void store(Employee employee) {
    entityManager.persist(employee);
}

@Override
public Employee findEmployeeWithNumber(int employeeNumber) {
    return entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeNumber);
}

}
```

In my client I just call create() on the session bean, set all properties **except** the id field which is in my case employeeNumber. Afterwards I call store() and pass the object to the session bean. The object is then stored propperly in the database and the primary key is generated automatically by the mysql database.

**Problem**

My problem is, that the generated id is not passed back to the object. So after calling store() and therefore entityManager.persist() a call of getEmployeeNumber() allways returns 0. According to many things I read on the web the @Id field should be automatically be populated by the id generated by the database. Hopefully somebody can help me with that. entityManager.flush() doesn't solve the problem.

**Further Details**

I am using JBoss 7.1.0 and MySQL 5.6. MySQL JDBC Driver is put in deployment folder.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="EmployeePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLEmployeeManagementDS</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLEmployeeManagementDS" pool-name="MySQLEmployeeManagementDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar
                </driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>
                        10
                    </min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        100
                    </max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>
                        true
                    </prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>
                        false
                    </use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>
                        FailingConnectionOnly
                    </flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        root
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        test
                    </password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>
                        com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
                    </xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`employee_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`inital` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`street` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`house_number` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`postalcode` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`department` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sallery_group` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`employee_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: whats your employeeNumber before persist? 0 or null? Is the employeeNumber set as the PK???

Comment: As employeeNumber in the entity bean is of type int, it is 0 from the beginning and it never changes. Null is not possible on int as far as I know it and yes, employe_number is the column in the database and it is set as PK

Comment: You are right, i usually use Long for id, its a good practice to use Long instead of int for id´s... Whats about my third question? did you set employeeNumber as the PK?

Comment: Yes I did, see the additional listing above :)

Comment: You're letting both hibernate AND mysql generate a primary key for the record. I don't know if that's the problem but you could check it (for example by removing the auto increment from the create table script.)

Comment: @Ozzie where is hibernate is generating a primary key? Doesn't @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) tell Hibernate that the primary key is generated by the database and not by Hibernate? Would be thankful for your clarification.

Comment: Are you using remote or local interface EJB?

Comment: The interface has a @Remote annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the behaviour you observe is correct. When you use GenerationType.IDENTITY or GenerationType.SEQUENCE strategy, the id value is not known before the row is inserted.

If you need that value right after persisting entity, you have to call EntityManager.flush() to force synchronization with database and then retrive your object - it will have the id set at that time.

You may also try to use HQL query, not find method

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select e from Employee where e.id = :id");
q.setId(employeeNumber);
return q.getSingleResult()
```

Another problem might arise if you use EJB with remote interface. Assuming the following flow

1. On the client side you call EmployeeManagementBean.create(), then you get Employee object on the client side, lets call it e1.
2. On the client side you call EmployeeManagementBean.store(e1)
3. On the client side you call e1.getEmployeeNumber() and you get 0

the problem is the following. When you call EmployeeManagementBean.store(e1) the copy of the e1 object is passed to EJB method, the object is modified on the server side, but the original object on the client side does not. This is because during remote EJBs calls arguments are passed to server as a serialized copies of the original objects.

So remote changes on the server side (e.g. changing id) are not seen on client side.

In order to overcome this you can change store method as follows:

```
public Employee store(Employee employee) {
    entityManager.persist(employee);
    entityManager.flush();
    return employee; //employee should have id set to the DB value
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I allready tried calling flush as I found that in several other topics concerning the same problem. Sadly it doesn't work. Any other hints?

Comment: Have you tried to use HQL query in place of find(), see updated answer

Comment: Doesn't your query require me to know the id? This exactly is my problem, that i don't have access to the id of the newly inserted object :(

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much. It fixed my problem by just returning the object :-) It even worked without the flush. What would be a better way to do it? I guess with the flush to ensure context and database are in sync?